# Javascript Regex remove specialchars except - and æøå

Tags: javascript, regex

I got this:

```
var stringToReplace = 'æøasdasd\89-asdasd sse';
var desired = stringToReplace.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
alert(desired);
```

I found the replace rule from another SO question.

This works fine, it gives output:

```
asdasd89asdasd sse
```

Although I would like to set up additional rules:

1. Keep `æøå` characters
2. Keep `-` character
3. Turn whitespace/space into a `-` character

So the output would be:

```
æøåasdasd89-asdasd-sse
```

I know I can run an extra line: 
    stringtoReplace.replace(' ', '-');

to accomplish my 3) goal - but I dont know what to do with the 1 and 2), since I am not into regex expressions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
str = str.replace(/[^æøå\w -]+/g, '').replace(/ +/g, '-');
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/d60qrX

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Works almost great. Try with this input ´æøasdasd\89-asdasd sse e a sd s´ it does replace all the whitespace with -

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the special characters to the exclusion list.

```
/[^\w\sæøå-]/gi
```

Fiddle with example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/M4wkK/).

And as you said - you can use another replace to replace spaces with dashes

Answer (score 0):

Your original regex `[^\w\s]` targets any character which isn't a word or whitespace character (`-`, for example). To include other characters in this regex's 'whitelist', simply add them to that character group:

```
stringToReplace.replace(/[^\w\sæøå-]/gi, '');
```

As for replacing spaces with hyphens, you cannot do both in a single regex. You can, however, use a string replacement afterwards to solve that.

```
stringToReplace.replace(" ","-");
```